# Python converting time zone into hours?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm running some Django unit tests, and one of them involves creating timezone-aware datetimes.

My time stamp starts out as the string: `2011-12-05 00:00:00-07:00`, which gets passed to the model constructor.

When I print the string stored in the model, I get: `2011-12-05 07:00:00+00:00`. Why is the timezone offset being stored as the hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms

so it's not timezone converted to hours, but datetime converted to UTC timezone.